# Display scrollbar inside wordpress widget area

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a widget in my wordpress site that displays last 10 posts. The whole display image+title with 10 posts make the widget looks huge. I was thinking if its easy/possible to display only a specific size for example 300 pixels and have a small scrollbar on the right to see the rest content.

[Example](http://s23.postimg.org/8jadydjsb/image.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#recent-posts-widget {
    height: 300px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

Above is the most simple way to achieve this (replace `#recent-posts-widget` in your CSS with the selector of the widget container on your site).  Need to see the relevant HTML markup and CSS to give you more specific instruction.

That will produce a "default" scrollbar like you see at the side of the browser window.  If you want something less ugly that you can style further to be like your site, look into using [jScrollPane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/) which allows for much more beautiful scrollbars and has great cross-browser compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to set `max-height:300px` and `overflow:scroll` of the specific widget (each widget has it's own class/id, set this inside your style.css).

This should give you a vertical scrollbar if the widget is bigger than 300px.

Hope this helps :)